# Best tool to loosen shower faucet that is secured from the back?

Tags: plumbing, shower, faucet

My goal is to replace the washer in this tap.

I have been unable to do this because I need to be sure *how* to unscrew the tap and/or *why* it cannot be unscrewed.

There is no nut at the front or screw on the side. There are 2 notches on the disk at the back.

Here are pictures:

[image]

[image]

I tried a tool with 2 prongs but I could not get enough force to loosen it. It was pretty cheap tool though and the prongs ended up breaking off:

[image]

Is there a better tool or method to loosen it?

Comment: not following. What makes you think it is tighten from the back. The second photo is useless

Comment: No nut at front, no worm nut in side, can place the pronged tool. Photo is lower resolution due to this site’s size limit so sorry about that. It definitely has 2 notches round the back indicative of these being used to unscrew it.

Comment: if you say so, but it would be the most stupid design I have ever seen. Are you trying to remove the handle then the valve

Comment: Is there a set screw somewhere on the shaft or the collar of the valve handle?  Can you turn the outer collar with a large pliers?  (or is all that wear from your attempts to do that?)

Comment: Outer collar does come loose. Since the photo I have used pliers to get it off because it didn't have the friction to use the rubber belt tool to unlock it. But it needs the tap off to come off completely. I believe that once the tap and the sleeve are off I will then be able to change the washer easily.

Comment: I see you've edited the text a bit, and that's helpful. I think the biggest issue is that second picture is nothing but a blurry mess that could be just about anything. Please keep trying to get pictures until your camera gives you one that's actually in focus on the part we need to see to help us help you.

Comment: Update: Plumber came out. Turned out the whole thing was seized up so couldn't be taken off. Turns out that undoing the sleeve, using grips, allows access to a nut which when unscrewed the whole piece comes out.

Answer (score 2):

The second photo is too blurry to make out any detail, but if those really are slots for a pin spanner, then you might get away with a 2-pin adjustable  angle grinder spanner [wrench]

[image]

They're cheap as chips, so if you can't find one in a store you can measure for size you could throw a couple of quid/bucks/shekels at one online.

Your main issue might be guessing which way the thread goes. I'd hope it would be right-handed, so looking from the front it would unscrew clockwise.

Comment: counterclockwise. Righty tighty lefty loosey.

Comment: @Gil - The screw is facing away from you, it's on the back face of the actual tap head. So if you're facing the wall - for which you have no real alternative, then it's clockwise.

Comment: Sorry I did not under your question. You said "looking from the front it would unscrew clockwise", you did not say the front of what so I assumed it was the head of the screw. This would make it CCW from the back of the screw.

Comment: @Gil - it's all there in the OP's question, even if it is blurry.

Comment: Thanks @Tetsujin, I tried both ways! I first tried clockwise from my perspective (counter clockwise from it's perspective) and it didn't move a millimeter! Tried the other way. Same thing. Thanks for the tool recommendation.

Comment: I have a hunch the pins will be too wide. The pins would need to be < 1mm probably to fit, but on ones I have seen online they are 3mm.

Comment: Use a file. These things are cheap enough to be considered disposable.